# cannot import name 'main' [instalar y actualizar pip3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Tras instalar pip3 actualizarlo con `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
 y `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, al instalar cualquier paquete o módulo, en este caso 'future' me reporta el error:

```
$ pip3 install future
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

He probado a reinstalar pip3 pero me reporta el mismo problema.

Comment: el codigo del fichero  pip3 es: `#!/usr/bin/python3
# GENERATED BY DEBIAN

import sys

# Run the main entry point, similarly to how setuptools does it, but because
# we didn't install the actual entry point from setup.py, don't use the
# pkg_resources API.
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguna vez me paso lo mismo y esta es la solución que encontré, probablemente no sea la mejor practica pero a mi me ayudó.

Dependiendo de la instalación el archivo pip se localiza en `/usr/bin/` o en `/usr/local/bin/`, una vez que estamos en el directorio localizamos el archivo pip y lo abrimos para editarlo (`sudo nano /usr/local/bin/pip`) y reemplazamos su contenido por:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Guardamos y volvemos a ejecutar el comando pip que necesitamos y todo debería funcionar correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Al actualizar `pip` te has puesto una versión 10 o superior, que ya no acepta `pip.main()` para instalar paquetes.

La solución es volver a una versión anterior y dejar tiempo a debian para que se actualice al nuevo pip.

Una forma segura de hacer funcionar el `pip3` es invocarlo como si fuera un módulo:

```
$ sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

Para otra vez, procura no hacer cambios en la instalación python del sistema. El instalador `pip` puede instalar los módulos únicamente para el usuario, sin afectar para nada al sistema (eg: opción `--user`).

Comment: tambien seria recomendable que use un virtualenv ;)

Comment: lo tendre en cuenta, sin embargo me gustaria conocer tu justificacion para que el sistema no me deje instalar el paquete future, necesario para un framerwork. 
zer0day@zer0day-X555LD ~/routersploit $ python3 -m pip install future/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip
` a razon a que se debe?

Comment: Tienes una instalación de python3 *local* sin el módulo pip. Usa la ruta del sistema `/usr/bin/python3`. O instala `pip` en local: `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==9.0.3`

Comment: esa es la parte sencilla, pero el problema persiste . No detecta el paquete, a pesar de tener los paquetes pip y future instalados en python 2 y3.  Si te parece te dejo un pastebin con el codigo que ofrece la consola donde ves realmete que esta instado pero sin embargo me reporta que no esta instalado 'future'. Codigo en:  https://pastebin.com/HAB4xqJX . Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Es mejor que todo añadido a tu pregunta lo edites en tu pregunta inicial. Esto no es un chat y la idea es que sea útil para todos. Tienes 3 instalaciones de python: sistema, /usr/local y ~/.local . Además, lo estará duplicado como python2 y python3, en total 6. Localiza a cuál de ellas apuntan los comandos `python3` y `pip3`. En caso de duda, quita de la variable de entorno `$PATH` todos los directorios locales. Además, siendo debian, es posible que estés usando `update-alternatives` (compruébalo con `update-alternatives --list python`).